# CreateProcess Error = 5 Access Denied in Robotframework Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework, automation-testing

I am trying to do automation database testing with robotframework in Pycharm. On running the Test Case I am getting this error:

> Error running 'run current file' Cannot run program "C:\Users\Maaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts" (in directory "C:\Users\Maaz\PycharmProjects\Test_Project"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied